# Why does "How Do You" trigger a "likely closed" warning on SO?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When looking to Stack Overflow for help, I often find myself phrasing questions like so:

> How do you XXX

to which Stack Overflow throws me a warning box:

> "Your question appears subjective and is likely to be closed".

Why does this happen?  What is so subjective about this phrasing that warrants the likely closing of a question?

What make these (valid, highly-voted, *protected*) examples acceptable?

- [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)
- [How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/how-do-you-create-a-remote-git-branch)
- [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)
- [How do you set, clear, and toggle a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

### Edit:

It is clear this mechanism analyses the question and proposes hints to authors that may help keep SO clean.  It is also clear that these are *hints* and may not apply in every single case.  I understand that, and that is **not** my question.

My question is *specifically* with regard to this *particular* hint, and why the *single act* of writing a title beginning with the string `How do you` triggers this warning.

Comment: The warning isn't foolproof, by design.  It's just a heuristic that looks for red flags.  It doesn't mean that the question is *necessarily* bad, just that it has certain traits that tend to be seen in bad questions, rather than good ones.  You should take a closer look and make sure you don't have any of the problems that it warns about.  If you're confident that it was a false positive, then feel free to ignore it.

Comment: I understand that.  I am asking because the "certain traits" you refer to appear to be limited (in this example) to a single "trait": the question title beginning with the string "How do you".  It appears very broad, and I am curious as to why.

Comment: What makes you so sure that it's the phrase "how do you" that triggers the warning, and not something else in your posts?

Comment: Trial and error, having written many questions and become very familiar with the question submission interface.

Comment: @Servy I just tested it, with nothing more than a short title of "How do you trigger warning" and "How do you title" and got that warning. I also tried a more realistic title: "How do you check the length of an array" and got the warning. I'm 99% sure that "how do you" is triggering this warning. (Checks done on SO specifically.)

Comment: That particular warning does seem a bit odd... considering the push for those kinds of questions not being off topic a few years ago... There's far more *useful* "How do i do X" questions than "X doesn't work" questions.

Comment: I prefer titles of the "How to" instead.

Comment: @Braiam that forms a statement, not a question, and would be more suited to the title of a blog describing how to solve the problem than a Q&A site asking for assistance (ie: a page which could potentially never actually contain the solution)

Comment: How to write a good title? <-- How is that not a question? BTW, titles are for 1. the potential answerers (who needs to know what you are up to) 2. the future readers (that normally find the question through search engines).

Comment: @Braiam Please see [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56625) on the English StackExchange describing this.

Comment: And there are opposite views in the answers of that question: one of the most *popular* is that is not "standard".

Comment: @Braiam I don't think this discussion is constructive.  Perhaps share your opinion on that question instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The warning is triggered simply by the presence of the word "you" in the title.  A title like "Foo bar baz you whatever" will trigger it; a title like "How do *I* do this thing?" will not.

The purpose of the check is to warn users who ask subjective questions like "What is your favorite programming language?" or "How do you indent your C code?"  Alas, it's just a simple regexp check, and not smart enough to realize that sometimes the word "you" is actually a [generic you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you), and not actually addressing the audience.

In any case, if you're sure that your question is on-topic for SO, feel free to ignore the warning.  Or, alternatively, just rewrite the title not to use the word "you".

Comment: "How can I" is an easy fix.

Comment: TODO(me):  Create popular programming language called "you".