# I want to know if people get a warning when their question title starts with "I want to"

Tags: support, title, question-quality

According to my non-researched casual observations, questions with titles (and possibly also bodies) beginning with "I want to..." are usually non-question requirement dumps. [Here's a recent example that prompted me to ask about this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417383/i-want-to-write-a-program-in-php-that-calculate-the-electricity-bill)

I was just curious if someone trying to post a question like that would get any kind of warning that their question was likely to be poorly received. If not for that particular phrase, are there any other "red flag" type phrases that prompt some kind of "are you sure?" warning that people have to click through to post the question?

Comment: Currently no they dont get a warning.

Comment: I want to say you should have gotten an answer to your question when you asked it.

Comment: @AlexL yeah, I thought about that, but I thought it might be different on the main site and I didn't want to experiment there.

Comment: Perhaps not a warning, but an automated silent "off-topic" flag could take place? Cause then they just remove "I want to" and still submit.

Comment: @AlexL An automatic flag goes a bit too far in my opinion, but I wasn't trying to make a feature request, though. I was just wondering if any checks like that existed already.

Comment: Sure there is a good warning, you can tell from half a mile away that the question is junk.  How is that question going to be any better with a different title?  It is fairly amazing that enough SO users looked at it anyway to get it closed.  But good opportunity for some servings of snark perhaps.

Comment: @HansPassant I was thinking that a warning prompted by something like that would indicate that the question shouldn't be posted, not that the title should be changed. (Sure, I know a lot of people would just go ahead and post it anyway.)

Comment: I do get this warning: *Questions with similar titles have frequently been downvoted and/or closed. Consider using a title that more accurately describes your question.*

Comment: @rene Did you try to post an "I want to " Q? I was kind of worried about doing that. I'm a bit disappointed that changing the title is what they want you to consider doing, in that case.

Comment: What is wrong with a question: "*I want to [...]. I tried [...]. This is the code I tried [...]. That failes [...]. __[Final Question Here like: Where do I err?]__*" <== This comment is in regard *(and possibly also bodies)*

Comment: @Don'tPanic no, the ajax calls for validate-title and /search/titles fire on blur of the title field. The notification text comes from the call to /search/titles.

Comment: Yes, it's just one of those touchstones that has you reaching for dv/cv before the question is open.   It joins 'explain', 'confused', 'given', 'doubts' etc. as almost 100% indicators of a bad question.  Should be left in as a signal to ignore unless you want to moderate.  If you are in an 'answer a good question' mood, you can then just skip opening such things and save yourself some votes for later when the REALLY bad questions come in.

Comment: @derM nothing, of course. I don't think those words _guarantee_ on off-topic question, I just think there's a strong correlation.

Comment: @rene I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @MartinJames I'm a little disappointed that you didn't include 'PHP' in that list ;)

Comment: @MartinJames As far as not opening them, the only reason I do open questions like that is specifically to VTC. But I thought it would be cool if they had a little better chance of just not existing to begin with.

Comment: @Don'tPanic there a tag for that.  There should be a tag for 'confused' etc too, so it's easier to filter them out:)

Comment: I think stuff like that is very much needed in a heuristics that pushes questions into [meta-tag:triage] queue

Comment: From now on, I will start my question titles with _I wanna_.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I think that's fine as long as you change your last name to Ramone.

Comment: How about _I really really really wanna_ and change your whole name to match one of the Spice Girls?

Comment: I'm surprised that having a personal pronoun doesn't prompt that obnoxious popup, like in "How do I ...", which prompts people to say "How to ...". **Edit**: Oops, it's "How do you ..." https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343833/why-does-how-do-you-trigger-a-likely-closed-warning-on-so?rq=1

Comment: Whenever I see these questions on Meta, I always wonder how worth it is to add these special cases by hand. Would adding these warnings really help? Are questions with this title getting asked so often and are off-topic so often that it's causing a strain on the StackOverflow ecosystem? I'm not sure...

Comment: [Meta] Should this question be flagged for starting with "I want to"? :)

Comment: 18.000+ questions with I want to in the title that are not closed. The top ones are okay is, but as soon as you scroll down the lesser quality starts to pour in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22i+want+to%22+closed%3Ano

Comment: They should get a lifetime ban if they start the question with "I wanna..."

Comment: We should force all questions to start with "I want to". There are far too many questions that are unclear because people fail to say what they want to achieve.

Comment: @MichaelKay The other problem is when they *only* say that, with no evidence that they've made any effort at all, so the implication is _'I want to do X. Get to work. Hurry up! I'm waiting.'_

Comment: We should auto-flag questions starting by "Write". Like "write a program doing this & that" ... homework dump.

Comment: Alrighty.. so much for fun and rants, but really, how about constructing a metric that counts occurences of "words unlikely to indicate a good question" over the title and body of the question, and calculating an "estimated time to be closed" basing on already-closed questions that use similar words, and displaying that estimation with red bold font if the time-to-kill is, say, less than 1hour? I'm personally not that good at data mining and stats, but maybe that idea has some potential?

Comment: [No.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJH9w.png)

Answer (score -5):

No, there is no such flag. Whoever that might be asking a question might want to explain what he/she is trying to achieve before stating the problem for clarity.

Comment: That would be best done in the question *body*, not the title, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yea, you're right