# New users with the intent of "I want to"

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions

What I'm talking about are predominantly new users, who visit the site with the intent of "I want to".

When reviewing & closing [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%20want%22) I've noticed, that there is a certain kind of questions, which is starting with or containing the phrase "I want to", which are often too broad and show no research or attempt. They either a) have an outstanding score or b) are being put on hold. Here on meta, this kind of [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22I%20want%22) also exists, but it doesn't show the same extremes.

And so "I wanted to" ask, how to handle them properly or if not the "New Question" form could look for this phrase, as it does with possible duplicates? If the [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section would prominently feature a "how-to ask", when the intent is "I want to", this might reduce the moderation workload, which this kind of often rather unspecified questions may cause.

There's a certain difference in between "I want to - but I don't know how" (which is an intent, which may also result in requests for off-site resources) and "I want to - and this is where I've got stuck".

So far I have no query/numbers, which would support my claim of questions containing said phrase, which were put on hold, but based upon my impression, I'd assume that the data would support this.

Comment: [Paging Tiny Giant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp/338846#338846). (Also: [How should we be advising users asking too broad or unclear how-to questions while not implying that such questions require code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370152/how-should-we-be-advising-users-asking-too-broad-or-unclear-how-to-questions-whi))

Comment: I noticed this too a while back. I asked [this similar question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359640/i-want-to-know-if-people-get-a-warning-when-their-question-title-starts-with-i) about it. I actually really like how-to questions when they're properly specified, regardless of what/if they tried, but "I want to" questions often seem too vague to produce good answers.

Comment: Regarding the third paragraph you added, I don't see a problem with either of them so long as the question is specific, answerable, and otherwise on-topic. Stack Overflow makes no requirement that you know how to do something in order to ask a question about it... otherwise we wouldn't allow debugging questions, arguably our most popular topic. What matters is the rest of the question... if the entire question is "I want to do X but don't know how", then yeah, that's probably Too Broad, but not because they told us what they want to do... but rather because that's *all* they told us.

Comment: Tempted to edit this post to start with: "I want to talk about are predominantly new users..."

Comment: Heh, missed the page, but yeah how-to questions aren't inherently off-topic. They just have to be reasonably scoped (asking how to accomplish one or two directly linked tasks, not multiple loosely or completely unrelated taskes) and well-defined (the thing being asked for must not be open to interpretation). All of this is _why_ I posted that question asking if we could come up with some better standard advice for those users asking too broad or unclear how-to questions while not implying that such questions require code.

Answer (score 14):

Everyone asking a question wants to *do something*, regardless of why they are asking. Some of us want to find the solution to a problem we have at work, some are working on homework/school work, some want to learn why a thing works the way it does for its own sake...

So you should handle them the same way you handle every other question:

- if the question is close-worthy, vote to close it
- if the question is not close-worthy, don't vote to close it

If you find the phrase distracting, feel free to remove it when performing edits to otherwise improve or clarify such questions. But there's nothing inherently problematic about the phrase "I want to" vs any other necessary English phrase such as "I'm trying to" or "I have a ...", etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a fairly large variety of questions containing the words "I want". There's some great ones, showing a full MCVE, and then there's [some terrible ones](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=3361&tab=Votes&q=%22I%20want%22%20closed%3ayes) that have already been closed and heavily downvoted. You should handle these questions just as you would handle any other question. A single phrase does not automatically make a question good or bad.

If the question needs to be closed, vote to close. If the question needs to be rephrased to sound less like a homework question, edit it. Just do what you would do for any other question.

Comment: I didn't mean to generalize too much (and not talking about the ones, which show research or attempt) and I would not judge based upon the phrase only; nevertheless questions containing the phrase just often are quite similar and fall into a pattern.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I see what you're saying: there are a fair number of no-MCVE questions containing "I want". But just handle these questions as you would any other question, because, as I said, not all of these are bad.